# Thread Count Slowly Increasing with Asyncio in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm currently working on a Python script that will be left running for a long period of time. There is a function I wish to run repeatedly so I have created a class with a static wrapper method that I pass the function to and call with asyncio. When this function completes or if there is a crash I handle it and restart the function:

```
class ContinuousProcessWrapper:

    @staticmethod
    async def run_continuous_process(function):
        while True:
            try:
                await function()
            except Exception as e:
               logging.error(e)
               logging.warning("Restarting Continuous Process...")
```

I call this wrapper a function from my `main()` method like this:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(
        ContinuousProcessWrapper.run_continuous_process(logging_workflow))
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

My function looks something like this:

```
async def logging_workflow():
    data_processor = DataProcessor(Settings.environment)

    data_client = Client(Settings.account)
    data_client.connect()

    if len(market_ids) > 0:
        # run task here
    else:
        logging.info(f"Sleeping")
        sleep(3600)
```

It's running fine and restarting as it should but using [Monit](https://mmonit.com/) to track memory usage etc. I've noticed that it starts with 2 threads but then each time the function is called again the thread count increases by 1. I'm guessing this indicates that something isn't being disposed and a thread is being left idle?

Do you know how I can clear up the threads so they don't continue to increase? Or have any suggestions on how this could be done in a more Pythonic way (I'm a C# dev most of the time)
I would have thought asyncio would do this for me after the await but maybe not.

Comment: Unlike C# asyncio in Python **doesn't start threads** on its own. Most likely you incorrectly use either `DataProcessor` or `Client` objects, whatever these things are. One of them most likely spawns a thread that you never signal to stop.

Comment: Thanks @freakish you're right. That was the issue!